# Does running a long task on lapply increase used memory?

Tags: r

I'm planning on performing a permutation test on a list of dataframes but I'm concerned I will run out of memory at some point. Suppose I have the following toy-example:

```
f <- function(x) {
  some_intermediate_value <- mean(x)
  to_be_returned_value <- some_intermediate_value^2
  return(to_be_returned_value)
}

out <- lapply(list_of_objects, f)
```

Suppose the list_of_objects is very long. Will R use more and more memory the longer lapply is running? In other words, will the fact that the function `f` keeps making variables (`some_intermediate_value` and `to_be_returned_value`) make it so memory will run out at some point, or does R's memory management take care of this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out @hadley's pryr package, I believe it shows that memory usage will remain constant,

```
# install.packages('pryr')
library(pryr)

f <- function(x) {
  some_intermediate_value <- mean(x)
  to_be_returned_value <- some_intermediate_value^2
  print(pryr::mem_used())
  return(to_be_returned_value)
}

out <- lapply(
  # large list ~ 669MB
  list(x1 = rnorm(1e7),
       x2 = rnorm(1e7),
       x3 = rnorm(1e7),
       x4 = rnorm(1e7)),
  FUN = f)

669 MB
669 MB
669 MB
669 MB
```

http://adv-r.had.co.nz/memory.html